# Equivalent of a python generator in C++ for buffered reads

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, file, io

Guido Van Rossum demonstrates the simplicity of Python in this [article](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/sorting-million-32-bit-integers-in-2mb.html) and makes use of this function for buffered reads of a file of unknown length:

```
def intsfromfile(f):
    while True:
        a = array.array('i')
        a.fromstring(f.read(4000))
        if not a:
            break
        for x in a:
            yield x
```

I need to do the same thing in C++ for speed reasons! I have many files containing sorted lists of unsigned 64 bit integers that I need to merge. I have found this nice piece of [code](http://code.google.com/p/kway/) for merging vectors.

I am stuck on how to make an **ifstream** for a file of unknown length present itself as a **vector** which can be happily iterated over until the end of the file is reached. Any suggestions? Am I barking up the correct tree with an **istreambuf_iterator**?

Comment: Are the integers in the file separated by newline characters, spaces, etc.? If so, the `istream_iterator` is your friend.

Comment: @Toolbox thanks for the reply and the solution! The format of the files is binary, 64-bit little-endian unsigned integers with no separator. So looks like istreambuf_iterator is the way to go? Can you help with disguising istreambuf_iterator as a vector<unsigned long>?

Comment: Sure! Give me a few moments to whip something up (and make sure it compiles).

Comment: for future reference, generators can be seen as input iterators in C++. The syntax is not as nice, obviously, since you have to maintain the state yourself, but it does work :)

Comment: Sorry! I totally forgot to post an example of the `istreambuf_iterator`'s usage. I have edited one into my answer, though I'm not totally satisfied with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to disguise an `ifstream` (or really, any input stream) in a form that acts like an iterator, you want to use the `istream_iterator` or the `istreambuf_iterator` template class. The former is useful for files where the formatting is of concern. For example, a file full of whitespace-delimited integers can be read into the vector's iterator range constructor as follows:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator> // needed for istream_iterator

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ifstream infile("my-file.txt");

    // It isn't customary to declare these as standalone variables,
    // but see below for why it's necessary when working with
    // initializing containers.
    istream_iterator<int> infile_begin(infile);
    istream_iterator<int> infile_end;

    vector<int> my_ints(infile_begin, infile_end);

    // You can also do stuff with the istream_iterator objects directly:
    // Careful! If you run this program as is, this won't work because we
    // used up the input stream already with the vector.

    int total = 0;
    while (infile_begin != infile_end) {
        total += *infile_begin;
        ++infile_begin;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`istreambuf_iterator` is used to read through files a single character at a time, disregarding the formatting of the input. That is, it will return you all characters, including spaces, newline characters, and so on. Depending on your application, that may be more appropriate.

Note: Scott Meyers explains in *Effective STL* why the separate variable declarations for `istream_iterator` are needed above. Normally, you would do something like this:

```
ifstream infile("my-file.txt");
vector<int> my_ints(istream_iterator<int>(infile), istream_iterator<int>());
```

However, C++ actually parses the second line in an incredibly bizarre way. It sees it as the declaration of a function named `my_ints` that takes in two parameters and returns a `vector<int>`. The first parameter is of type `istream_iterator<int>` and is named `infile` (the parantheses are ignored). The second parameter is a function pointer with no name that takes zero arguments (because of the parantheses) and returns an object of type `istream_iterator<int>`.

Pretty cool, but also pretty aggravating if you're not watching out for it.

---

**EDIT**

Here's an example using the `istreambuf_iterator` to read in a file of 64-bit numbers laid out end-to-end:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ifstream input("my-file.txt");
    istreambuf_iterator<char> input_begin(input);
    istreambuf_iterator<char> input_end;

    // Fill a char vector with input file's contents:
    vector<char> char_input(input_begin, input_end);
    input.close();

    // Convert it to an array of unsigned long with a cast:
    unsigned long* converted = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&char_input[0]);
    size_t num_long_elements = char_input.size() * sizeof(char) / sizeof(unsigned long);

    // Put that information into a vector:
    vector<unsigned long> long_input(converted, converted + num_long_elements);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I personally rather dislike this solution (using `reinterpret_cast`, exposing `char_input`'s array), but I'm not familiar enough with `istreambuf_iterator` to comfortably use one templatized over 64-bit characters, which would make this much easier.

Comment: I am currently out of votes for today, but if I had any left I'd upvote this. :-)  This is an excellent explanation.

Comment: @templatetypedef don't worry, I'm not :P

Comment: IIRC there are also ways to add extra parentheses to get around the parsing ambiguity, but this is ugly and fails at explicitness.

Comment: because I love to name things --> the last part of your question is dealing with what is known as *The Most Vexing Parse*. Good answer by the way.