# How does one convert generator functions to single-return functions?

Tags: c++, algorithm, generator

Below is the pseudo code of the first order logic back chaining algorithm from *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach*.

The problem is that the functions are defined as generators and I don't quite understand how to convert generators into single return functions. If this were a one-and-done function, a vector would be obvious. However, these are recursive calls so I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it. The c++ [generate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate/) functionality doesn't seem useful. Bach chaining is not a complete algorithm and I wouldn't know how much space I would need to allocate.

How does one convert generator functions to single-return functions?

[image]

Picture taken form Russell, Stuart; Norvig, Peter. *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach* (Page 338). Pearson Education. Kindle Edition.

Comment: You could use Boost::coroutines or modern C++ coroutines?

Comment: I thought that those were a c++ 20 addition. I'm restricted to c++11.

Comment: Boost::coroutines are then an option ;)

Comment: I can't use boost. It's a school project and the school servers don't have boost.

Comment: SO already has the answer, generators are iterators in c++:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059187/equivalent-c-to-python-generator-pattern

Comment: So, it's not a duplicate. I am asking how to turn the generators into single return functions. Please read the text in my question.

Comment: We told you. Use coroutines, or follow the pattern from the duplicate.

Comment: Ya, but no. You seem to not understand my question. Now that I've thought about it more, the answer to my question is probably the same as converting recursive functions into iterative functions. Do you understand how that answers my question and not what you're suggesting?